# What material properties are unpredictable (not reproducible) but can be measured consistently and at a low cost?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, materials, crystallography

I'm looking for a process to create a material which has some easy to measure properties.
These properties should be consistent over a long period.
It should be very hard (expensive) to predict/reproduce a material which results in the same measurable properties. Every material product should generate an unique measurement result and impossible (or very expensive) to product a second product with the same measurement result.

What process, material and/or measurement could be used?

Some context:
The goal would be block-chain backed physical cash currency.
The process should result in a 'coin' (material product).
The 'coin' can be 'read' (measurement of some over time consistent material properties) resulting in a 'coin-id' (measurement).
The producer of the 'coin' reads the coin-id and adds a block to the chain which contains the 'coin-id' and his signature of the 'coin-id' and spends some (crypto) currency value. The physical coin represents the spend (crypto) currency value. For ease of use the signature could be attached to the coin (bar or qr-code).
The blockchain also contains the certificates of the coin producers.
The coins can be exchanged in the physical world without changes on the blockchain.
A receiver of a coin can read (measure) the unique coin-id and scan the signature.
A receiver knows the certificates of the coin producers. A receiver can check the veracity by checking if the coin-id is signed by a known coin producer certificate.

*Addendum*

Let the cost to produce a coin be **c**.
Let the probability of a duplicate measurement be **p**.
Let the value represented by the coin be **v**.

Because the represented value should be a lot bigger than the cost of a coin. The value should be a factor **f** bigger than the cost.

$v=cf$

The minimal value to make forgery too expensive:

$v=\frac{c}{p}$

The maximal **p** should be:

$p=\frac{c}{v}$

So given a $c=0.1$\$ and $v=100$\$

then the maximum $p=\frac{0.1}{100}=0.001$

Or put otherway around: given a more realistic forgery probability of $p=10^{-10}$

Maximum $f=\frac{1}{p}$, $f=10^{10}$

So a coin given $c=0.1$\$ could have a maximum value of $v=0.1*10^{10}=1.000.000.000$\$

Comment: Such material could be reverse engineered and reproduced.

Comment: @Poutnik Entropy can be stored in the form of information, although it has none.

Comment: @Karl It can be, of course. But it would be more about material arrangement than material itself. The "coin" could contain some hologram with blockchain code or some public encryption key. The coin itself can be a common coinage alloy.

Comment: @Poutnik Of course it could be reverse engineered. Likewise, md5 can be broken, given enough effort. The question (as always) is "Where is the money". If breaking a thing costs too much, it is effectively unbreakable.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have meant it in context of a single, not structured, reproducibly managed material, as I have not at the time thought about heterogenous structured options.

Comment: A good red wine. Everyone knows that it is good, but it is impossible to make another bottle just like it. Measuring would be easy - just send me the bottle.

Comment: Process to create: sexual reproduction;  resulting material: fingerprints of the offspring (or retina patterns).

Comment: @KarstenTheis To get rich quick, I recommend the wine here. Cheers, and merry Christmas etc.!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Impossible for a homogeneous material, however ...

basically *every* nonhomogeneous material fits your description. Say the pattern of microphase separation in a copolymer. Or the arrangement of filler particles in a composite.

You just have to think of something that is not only easy to make, but also easy to measure, i.e. take a digital photo of (microscopes and MRT or µCT scanners are out, I guess):

Pour resin of say four colours into a round bin, so you have four differently-coloured pie pieces. Now take a fork and run it through the bin a few times, perhaps in a "random" fashion (rotation, speed, direction, duration).

Let resin set, and you get a disk ("coin") with a pattern that is impossible to regenerate, even if someone stole the random number, which you delete immediately after use, that initialised the fork movement. They'd get something that looks somewhat similar, but clearly distinguishable. If they tried ten thousand times, they might get one or two that look similar enough to fool your algorithm, but that forgery is uneconomic, so you're safe.

Of course someone could forge those coins by printing a photographed pattern onto a coin, just like you can photocopy a dollar note.

The bigger problem I see is to make sure the "measurement" never creates a false negative (negative==forged) outcome, *and* that it doesn't require you to save a multi-megabyte dataset for every single coin.

Comment: I thought about the pattern of crystals formed by cooling of a liquid metal (zinc?)

Comment: Good idea. They would keep the database of patterns of all released coins and any non-genuine coin would not match.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yea, but that's not very persistant. Put ten coins in your wallet, and they will be non-recognisable after a week.

Comment: Not if you cover them with transparent plastic. That's better, but not very persistent either. But wait, I have an even better idea...

Comment: The resin coin meets the requirement for processing; cheap and impossible (or at least the expensive) to reproduce. The difficulty will indeed be the 'measurement' to read the unique coin value. Your points are valid, the more unique a description (measurement), the higher the cost of forgery, but also the larger the 'unique value'. But if a handheld device could reduce the information of the optical pattern using an cryptographic hash function, the storage would be less.

Comment: @Hubert A hash doesn't work,  where any tiny difference (a scratch or sth.) makes the comparison fail, and you don't know why. You want a compression algorithm for the actual pattern, so you can quantify the difference between the thing on the blockchain and the picture of the coin in your hand.

Comment: I believe the nuclear weapons monitor folk have used glitter in epoxy as parts of seals before (with photographs). You could combine that with illumina-style coloured-dot imaging.

Comment: Like your answer but concerned about robustness of the material. As such, I provided my alternate suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

The OP asks: What process, material and/or measurement could be used?

Answer: Snowflake maker, dihydrogen monoxide, photograph (with metric ruler included). "Snowflake maker" is a vapor condenser from steam onto a cooler surface or simply from the vapor.

[image]

It is well-known that no two snowflakes are alike. The unscientific media (Ref 1) propose the opposite, but the scientific consensus is that the probability of finding two identical snowflakes is zero (Ref 2).

An advantage of Snowflake Bitcoin is that it requires a physical repository (a bank, but not a snowbank) with a temperature low enough to prohibit melting and sublimation (which would allow the snowflakes to grow or diminish). Antarctica might not be cold enough; the actual snowflakes might have to be stored in outer space, but that cost could be prohibitive. An alternate bank could be physical storage of the actual photographs, or digital images with a very high resolution.

Ref 1. https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna16759121

Ref 2. https://www.loc.gov/everyday-mysteries/meteorology-climatology/item/is-it-true-that-no-two-snow-crystals-are-alike/

Comment: Very seasonal, but the idea was that you cannot copy them, that excludes photographs, on paper or digital. And a currency that you cannot remove from the back does not need be represented as physical objects.

Comment: The photos are only the proof of ownership; the snowflakes are the product and cannot be duplicated, but are stored in the (very cold) bank. The snowflakes can be stored at great expense - for a time. The measurements are unique and irreproducible; the metric ruler can be augmented with another at 90 degrees, and  various angles can be specified, as well as opacities and reflectance. Trust in the bank grows over time; the numbered photos serve as the substitute coin and are traded. Like serially numbered dollar bills vs gold in Fort Knox. No counterfeiting possible!

Comment: Serially numbered bills have been counterfeited for centuries. If the copy is perfect, there is no way of knowing if a specific note is original. Even if you have a second one with the same number, you only know that you have a problem, but no solution.  A picture that has no representative in the bank would obviously be a fake, but for that you can also store a copy of the photo, or a hash of the digital picture. No need to keep the snowflake.

Comment: Gotta combine the snowflakes with NFTs!

Comment: The cold temperature would make handeling and exchanging the coin difficult. Is there an other crystallisation process that results in room temperature crystall-flakes?

Comment: @Hubert: Very good idea! I hadn't thought of materials other than ice/snow because there have been no claims of non-similarity of crystals. Many organic materials sublime, so if you catch them early, there will be many small crystallites forming. I have done this with dibenzofuran mp ~82C. Some materials sublime, but appear to wet the collector (or spread so thin, which is similar) and simply grow into a lump. But maybe there is more similarity between crystals because of higher temperatures - closer to some equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

As to what process, material and/or measurement could be used, the same that exists for minting metal alloy coins.

The material could be composed of said four (or more) alloys with the coin displaying an ID. The latter can be a mathematical function of associated chemical and electrical properties of said coin.

For example, an alloy of Ni, Sn, Fe and Zn may work based on the there actual (or predicted) respective variations in an anodic index ([see this Table](https://www.zygology.com/cms/upload_area/pdf/Zyg-Anodic-Index.pdf)).

So, a simple chemical (like density) and electrochemical measurements (electrical resistance) may provide in conjunction with engraved ID an authenticity check.

This concept differs from government issued coins in the respect they are crafted for corrosion resistance (to increase circulation life span) while these coins are minted for identification purposes primarily,

Coins are known historically to be robust instrument for currency, and said coins can also be made completely virtual by mathematical fitting algorithms (applied to a provided data string) based on actual coins with specified varying compositions, from which the ID is generated.

Note: this answer complies with the need to be measured consistently over time at a low cost.

Comment: Very clever to ingrave the ID so it will be a part of the material properties.

Comment: What now stops me from reproducing a single coin with the same ID and alloy composition? Also highly accurate density measurements are expensive, and accurately measuring the electrical resistance of a coin is basically impossible.

Comment: Karl: Alas, experimenting with actual produced coins will likely suggests needed specifics. By the way, how does a vending machine (accepting coins for payment) actually determine a fake coin? Idea: Take advantage of existing technology!